# Dropdown list for Insert/edit video

Tags: tinymce

I am integrating TinyMCE in my CMS and want to have a feature to choose a video/audio by selecting media icon instead of typing the path in Source field. 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zmlD.png]
I was able to achieve this for choosing images through image_list
but, did not have luck using [external_media_list_url](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:external_media_list_url)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing documentation for TinyMCE 3.x which is no longer being updated.  Your screenshot appears to be TinyMCE 4.x so you should look at the documentation for that release:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/

There are APIs to create your own file picker for TinyMCE 4:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback

...and example of that is here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/